# pywinautoを使って自動でリモートアプリを起動して接続したい

Tags: python, python3

#### 実現したいこと

pythonで[リモート接続のアプリ](https://www.fmworld.net/cs/azbyclub/qanavi/jsp/qacontents.jsp?PID=4110-2361)を起動して
リモート先、ID、PW入力後、自動で接続したいです。

#### 前提

pywinautoを使って、
リモートデスクトップ接続のアプリを起動して
リモート先、IDまで入力できましたが、
接続ボタンをクリックした後に他のダイアログが表示され
PW入力できないです。
どのように別のダイアログが表示されたら、パスワード入力できるようになりますか。
教えていただけると嬉しいです。

お手数ですが、よろしくお願いお願い致します。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
pywinauto.base_wrapper.ElementNotEnabled
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time

# リモートデスクトップを起動
app = Application().start("mstsc.exe")

# ダイアログが表示されるまで待機
dlg = app.top_window()
dlg.Wait('visible')

# コントロールを取得してIDとPWを入力
dlg['コンピューター(&C):Edit'].TypeKeys('192.168.1.11')  # 接続先のIPアドレスを入力

#オプションのメニューをクリック
dlg['Toolbarオプションの表示(&O)'].Click()

#接続先のuserアドレスを入力
dlg['ユーザー名:Edit'].select()
dlg['ユーザー名:Edit'].type_keys('{DELETE}') 
dlg['ユーザー名:Edit'].type_keys('user')


# 接続ボタンをクリックして接続
dlg['接続(&N)Button'].Click()


# 別のダイアログが表示されるのを待機
new_dlg = app.window()
new_dlg.Wait('visible')

#パスワード入力
new_dlg['パスワード:Edit'].type_keys('password')

#OKボタンをクリックして接続
new_dlg['OK(&N)Button'].Click()
```

Comment: これらの記事やそこに紹介されている情報が参考になるかもしれません。[Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html), [pywin32 / pywinauto not working properly in remote desktop when it is minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50299472/9014308), [Remote desktop connection using pywinauto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51074956/9014308), [Remote Desktop Connection Automation using pywinauto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69502180/9014308)

Comment: ちなみにそのような状況ならば、その前後でのスクリーンショットを撮ってその何処の何が問題なのかを画像で示した方が助言・回答が付きやすいと思われます。